# Compare rows of an array column with the headers of another data frame using Scala and Spark

Tags: arrays, scala, dataframe, apache-spark, match

I am using Scala and Spark.
I have two data frames.

The first one is like following:

```
+------+------+-----------+
| num1 | num2 |    arr    |
+------+------+-----------+
|   25 |   10 | [a,c]     |
|   35 |   15 | [a,b,d]   |
+------+------+-----------+
```

In the second one the data frame headers are

```
num1, num2, a, b, c, d
```

I have created a case class by adding all the possible header columns.

Now what I want is, by matching the columns num1 and num2, I have to check whether
the array in arr column contains the headers of the second data frame.
If it so the value should be 1, else 0.

So the required output is:

```
+------+------+---+---+---+---+
| num1 | num2 | a | b | c | d |
+------+------+---+---+---+---+
|   25 |   10 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 |
|   35 |   15 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 1 |
+------+------+---+---+---+---+
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to transform the array column `arr` into one column per possible value, that would contain whether or not the array contains that value.

If so, you can use the `array_contains` function like this:

```scala
val df = Seq((25, 10, Seq("a","c")), (35, 15, Seq("a","b","d")))
             .toDF("num1", "num2", "arr")

val values = Seq("a", "b", "c", "d")
df
    .select(Seq("num1", "num2").map(col) ++
            values.map(x => array_contains('arr, x) as x) : _*)
    .show
```

```
+----+----+---+---+---+---+
|num1|num2|  a|  b|  c|  d|
+----+----+---+---+---+---+
|  25|  10|  1|  0|  1|  0|
|  35|  15|  1|  1|  0|  1|
+----+----+---+---+---+---+
```

Comment: If there are more than "arr" columns in my first data frame, is it possible to use the above code? If it is so what changes should I have to make?

Comment: If arr_cols is the list of these array columns, you could do something like `values.map(x => arr_cols.map(arr => array_contains(col(arr), x))).reduce(_ || _).alias(x))`.